# Getting previous row in the same column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How do I get the previous row in the same column in SQL RedShift?

For each row/date, I'd like to find the next billable trigger (my expected results are filled in). See my logic in column C where I am comparing the current row's date in column A to the previous row's date in col B. For the first row, 9/8 is currently constant but I'd like to have it be 7 days from the first date.

How do I turn my excel logic into the SQL query?

[image]

Comment: use a `case expression` - and it would be better if you supply table name and column names it is also better if you provide sample data as reusable text (not images)

Comment: If I understand the logic correctly, this requires a recursive CTE or some other looping mechanism.  Redshift does not directly support such queries, so this needs to be done in a scripting language or application.

Comment: Yeah I did see redshift doesn't support recursive. Is there an alternative way? @GordonLinoff